# How to update a nested array value in mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb

I want update a array value that is nested within an array value: i.e. set

`status = enabled`

where `alerts.id = 2`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5496a8ed49847b6cd7c7b350"),
    "name" : "joe",
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "name": "my location",
            "alerts" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "status" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "status" : null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would have used the position `$` character, but cannot use it twice in a statement - multi positional operators are not supported yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

How do I issue a statement to only update the status field of an alert matching an id of 2?

**UPDATE**

If I change the schema as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5496ab2149847b6cd7c7b352"),
    "name" : "joe",
    "locations" : {
        "my location" : {
            "alerts" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "status" : "enabled"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "status" : "enabled"
                }
            ]
        },
        "my other location" : {
            "alerts" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "status" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : 4,
                    "status" : null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can then use:

```
update({"locations.my location.alerts.id":1},{$set: {"locations.my location.alerts.$.status": "enabled"}});
```

Problem is I cannot create indexes on the alert id :-(

Comment: You might want to reconsider your data model, if possible. Nested arrays like that are tricky to operate in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tommi, seems multi positional operators https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Answer (score 1):

it may be better of modelled as such, specially if an index on location and,or alerts.id is needed.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5496a8ed49847b6cd7c7b350"),
    "name" : "joe",
    "location" : "myLocation",
    "alerts" : [{
                    "id" : 1,
                    "status" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "status" : null
                }
            ]
}




{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5496a8ed49847b6cd7c7b350"),
    "name" : "joe",
    "location" : "otherLocation",
    "alerts" : [{
                    "id" : 1,
                    "status" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "status" : null
                }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are having a wrong tool for the job. What you have in your example is relational data and it's much easier to handle with relational database. So I would suggest to use SQL-database instead of mongo.

But if you really want to do it with mongo, then I guess the only option is to fetch the document and modify it and put it back.

Comment: Thanks Hequ, but cannot agree with this suggestion.